# htaccess rewrite not allowing PHP GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customer/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /customer/index.php?p=$1.php [L]
```

which rewrites things like `domain.com/contacts/viewcontact.php` to be `domain.com/contacts/viewcontact`

when i go to the domain

`domain.com/contacts/viewcontact?seq=123`

and then in PHP `echo $_GET["seq"];` it shows nothing.

I have also tried using

`domain.com/contacts/viewcontact&seq=123`

but this shows page not found

Comment: But why `/index.php?p=viewcontact.php` instead of `/viewcontact.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule` resets the query string (`?p=$1.php`), but doesn't append the existing query string.  Add the [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag to your rule and it will append the query string from the request to the new one, which should do what you want.